# Start multiple instances of the window service

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, window

I have created a windows service that reads an IBM MQ messages and processes them. My Win Service is currently designed OnStart it triggers a timer interval which calls the function that calls the class which does all the work (See code below).

What I am trying to accomplish is to scale (if that is the right word) the application, if there are a lot of messages on the queue to process we would like to run multiple instances/threads of the service. Ideal situation would be to have some type of configuration in the app.config that indicates how many threads or worker processes to have running. Is threading the right approach? Is there a better or preferred way? Right now what we are doing is installing a new instance of the service with a different name and it is getting quiet tedious.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Started", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        _myTimer.Interval = 500; // half a second
        _myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimer;
        _myTimer.AutoReset = false;
        _myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        //If you want the main program to go ahead and shut down after some period of time, regardless of whether it's obtained the lock, use Monitor.TryEnter. For example, this will wait 15 seconds.
        //bool gotLock = Monitor.TryEnter(_timerLock, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_timerLock))
        {
            // something has the lock. Probably shutting down.
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            MqSyncJob mqSyncJob = new MqSyncJob(eventLog1);
            mqSyncJob.ProcessSyncJobQueue();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            _myTimer.Start(); // re-enables the timer
            Monitor.Exit(_timerLock);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just `Parallel.ForEach` the items in the queue?

Comment: threading works but you dont have to have multiple instances of the service, just offload the processing to a new thread.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How would you do Parallel.ForEach? I am not familiar with Parallel. What does it do? I am unable to loop through items in the queue due to transactions, so I get one at a time.

Comment: @BugFinder Out plan was to add threading but didn't know if that was what is supposed to be done or there are other way? Could threading cause any issues with the service? In the example above that I provided would threading be used around the timer or around the actual mqSyncJob.ProcessSyncJobQueue();

Comment: I can't explain that all through a comment, but I would suggest to read up on TPL (the task parallel library) provided with .NET nowadays.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thank you for the advice. I will look into parallel processing based on a 2min research I might be able to work with it

Comment: @PatrickHofman this works like a charm - man you saved me :) thank you so much