# Is it possible to connect and receive message into IBM MQ using windows service or windows listener

Tags: c#, windows-services, ibm-mq

I found how to connect to IBM MQ using C# console application and receive message into queue but I don't want to write a console application . I want to write a windows service which will receive message into MQ . Is it possible ? Any clue any kind of link will be helpful regarding this . Please help .

Comment: This question might be helpful: [Start multiple instances of the window service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396090/start-multiple-instances-of-the-window-service).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an IBM MQ question.  This is a C# Windows service question because IBM MQ does not care if the application is run from a console or service.

If you know how to create a C# Windows service program then just add the IBM MQ code to it.

Remember to connect and open the queue once, on service startup and close and disconnect on service shutdown.

Comment: thank you for reply @Roger . Can you provide me any link or document that says how to connect to the MQ ?

Comment: @saha.jan in your question you said you found how to connect to MQ.  There are samples provided in the mq client install and google will find you even more.